How have Neural Networks Changed the Role of King Safety?
Magnus Carlsen recently mentioned that thanks to Neural Networks "my view on king safety short-term and long-term has changed and my understanding has improved so much since 2019 [...] you have now more an understanding of how to build a safe king, sacrificing material to weaken your opponents's king or safeguarding your own king".
Does anyone have more to say on this matter, particularly regarding the safeguard of one's own King?
Examples are really appreciated.

Note he didn't say NNUEs. He said "neural network engines", which presumably refers to Lc0.

This question interests me as well.
Editing my answer because I've found the game :-)
https://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=2577109
Just created this lichess study for the same game -- you can analyze conveniently:
https://lichess.org/study/tNn51M9u/bZvoQNYc
Interestingly, the Stockfish on lichess also evaluates the position as 0.0 after the q-sac (move 15).
I remember seeing this game live. Magnus as white sac-ed his queen for peanuts (in terms of material) right out of the opening. He got a massive initiative. The eval said the position was equal, i.e., white had massive compensation. Ultimately, due to time pressure etc., Magnus couldn't find his way, and the material difference ended up costing him the game.
As to king safety, notice that Magnus tries 31. g5 instead of taking the exchange. Stockfish doesn't like this move. However, the B on d5 is really strong, and attempting to open up the K makes sense. Stockfish also disapproves of Black's taking the g5 pawn on move 33. Not sure how LC0 will evaluate these positions.
In the post-game interview, Magnus was asked if he had used Neural Networks to prep this, and he sort of agreed, but didn't elaborate.
Let's find more examples together!

As you acknowledge, this doesn't answer the question.

Updated the answer with an actual example. Pls check.

I'd say the initiative here is rather due to massive development problems of Black than king safety, but then, I was always a fan of Steinitz - a king can defend himself very well, so let em roll :-)

You are right, but this is the only example I can find so far. Let's look for more examples.

I'll start with this 8-moves defensive King Walk by Stockfish in the heart of the middlegame from a1 to g2, escaping the intense pressure from the queenside of the board (Game 363 from the CCC 17 Blitz Finals)

"Run for your life" is a motiv known to chess strategy way before NN, so a single game doesn't mean much. I guess one could write a whole book about the OP's question, though. But first much more source material must be collected.
